# Помогите расставить запятые (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Учитывая, что в настоящее время реорганизация юридического лица является самым распространенным способом уклонения от уплаты долгов, с целью реализации прав кредитора реорганизуемого юридического лица, банк направил должнику требование о досрочном возврате кредитных средств и уплате процентов, которое оставлено без ответа.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, все запятые на месте.

Первые две запятые обязательны, они выделяют подчиненное предложение "в настоящее время реорганизация юридического лица является самым распространенным способом уклонения от уплаты долгов".

Третья запятая отделяет распространенное обстоятельство и явлается желательной, учитывая следующие факторы:

- "двойное" распространенное обстоятельство выражено деепричастным оборотом плюс существительное с предлогом и зависимыми словами;
- канцелярский стиль;
- запятая облегчает понимание текста.

"Для смыслового выделения или только попутного пояснения в художественной речи могут обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные именами существительными в косвенных падежах с предлогами и стоящие в середине или в конце предложения" (Розенталь)

Четвертая запятая отделяет подчиненное предложение "оставлено без ответа" и является обязательной.

Answer (score 0):

**Мне кажется, что одна запятая лишняя**: обособление  целевого оборота придает ему вставочный характер, а его следует однозначно связать с действиями банка.

Учитывая, что в настоящее время реорганизация юридического лица является самым распространенным способом уклонения от уплаты долгов, **с целью реализации прав кредитора реорганизуемого юридического лица** банк направил должнику требование о досрочном возврате кредитных средств и уплате процентов, которое оставлено без ответа.